# How to fix Dictionary setter issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, web-services

I have created a dictionary. But during Build it gives me error:

> Change 'INotificationMessage.AlertMessageList ' to be read-only by
>   removing the property setter

```
public interface INotificationMessage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the notification message list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The notification message list.
        /// </value>
        Dictionary<string, string> AlertMessageList { get; set; }
    }
```

Can please ayone assist me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you shouldn't have a public set for collections as this allows the list to be replaced. Just use:

```
Dictionary<string, string> AlertMessageList { get; }
```

To fix it you can add method for set that collection or use:

```
Dictionary<string, string> AlertMessageList { get; private set; }
```

See [Collection properties should be read only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx)

Comment: And if you need to set it force an implemation for getting the list, just add a method to the interface  void SetAlertMessageList(Dictionary<string,string> dict)

Dictionary<string,string> SetAlertMessageList()

Comment: @Raj Hello. Please accept the answer if it was helpful. If not then describe what is the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: @MegaTron can you please suggest how to add a method to the interface to set properties.

Comment: @Raj You need to add methods like described in comment by user1419979 to the interface. and then implement it but it should be a create as a new question. So if it was helpful please accept, create a new question and include a link to this question if it helps provide context